# Parsing Error, When load Android SDK

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk

After creating an Android application project I have found these two errors in console:

1. Error: Error parsing E:\Android\ANDadt\adt\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
2. Error: Error parsing E:\Android\ANDadt\adt\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml

Comment: I'm having this same issue! This message appeared after installing the available API 22 components, just 5 hours ago.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started?answertab=votes#tab-top

This worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a permission issue. Make sure you have writing permissions for that folder. Try starting Eclipse or the SDK Manager as Administrator.

Comment: Well,,,,i just delete the android-wear ARM EABL v7a System-Image and android-wear Intel x86 Atom System-Image from SDK,,,no need for this now in my app,,but i download this,,,

Comment: :) great... If it is working for you,, Just click on tick below my answer. (Accept it)

Answer (score 2):

in windows:

copy **devices.xml** file from

```
sdk\tools\lib\devices.xml
```

and paste(override it) to

```
sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
```

This solution worked for me(try it).

Comment: +1 I also had to replace `sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml` with `sdk\tools\lib\devices.xml`

Answer (score 0):

For OS X user this is the only thing work for me:

```
sudo ./eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy file devices.xml file(\sdk\tools\lib), and paste it to the location folder where the error occurred. This solution worked for me in Windows 10.