# Error loading the SDK when Eclipse starts

Tags: android, eclipse

I have already read varying answers to above question, but I have a specific problem.
When I start Eclipse it gives an error:

```
> Error Parsing:
> C:\android-sdk_r24.2-windows\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a
>     cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

This error happens when Eclipse automatically loads the SDK on startup.

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418443/android-sdk-error-when-loading-the-sdk

Comment: why not android studio? They have already announced officially that they are going to stop providing support to Eclipse!

Comment: just you should use upto api level 19 not more then 21 because of eclipse simulator device can not accept api level 21 to execute app...

Comment: @amitsharma But what to do if we want to support api level 22 also? Since I am working on a project which requires to support lollipop version of android .

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan you can use api 22 or 21 but android eclipse actual work on up to api level 19 only you can test his simulator as well

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I have faced the same **parse sdk loading** problem during eclipse startup like yours (Shown in image below)

[image: SDK load error]

The **solution** to above problem is to just **delete(uninstall)** the package **Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image** available under **Android** **5.1.1 (API 22)** if it's installed. (No need to uninstall whole 5.1.1 package). May be there is some eclipse bug with this package.

[image: solution image]

Finally **restart** eclipse to see your changes.

> **Edit**: If the problem still exists, try removing other Android Wear
>   package also (i.e **Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image**) as
>   suggested by @Abhishek in comments below.

Comment: I was still getting the error after deleting 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image'. Then I deleted 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image' under Android 5.1.1 (API 22) and finally all errors disappeared :)

Comment: @Abhishek glad that you solved your problem, based on your comment I'll update my answer.

Comment: It worked for me by removing all the Android Wear packages which is mentioned in the error log

Comment: Android Studio has the same problem when the app is ran. The same solution solved my problem.

Comment: Confirmed. I had to remove both to get Eclipse to work with my SDK (which I installed with Android Studio)

Comment: Deleted both Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image' & 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image' in API 23.  Solved my problem.

Comment: Had to delete all "wear" packages. Thanks.

Comment: I had to delete the Android Wear  under Android 5.1.1 and  under Android 6.0 , but it worked.

Comment: Mine was worked after deleting--- Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image ---- Under Android 6.0 (API23)

Comment: Why should we even have to do this?  Android can be so blooming annoying at times.

Comment: This help me lot i had some more error showing related to some installed Wear.i had delete them all.. it works for me thanks @AmritPalSingh

Comment: In my case it was Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image

Answer (score 37):

This was my error message:

> Error: Error Parsing
>   C:\Android\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:Skin'. No child
>   element is expected at this point.

There´s a kind of problem with android Wear packages for `API 22`, so my solution was deleting this two packages from the `API 22`

[image]

Comment: do you know why there is a problem with android wear in API 22. Previously there were no such issues. I have asked just for information purpose.

Answer (score 12):

The issue is still coming for API 23. To get rid from this we have to uninstall  android Wear packages for both API 22 and API 23 also (till current update).

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue and confirming that uninstall of Wear packages for both API 22 and 23 resolving the current problem

Answer (score 5):

Copy the  default devices.xml file from : 
/home/user/android-sdk/tools/lib/devices.xml

and paste it in the below paths:
/android-sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/
and
/android-sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86/

This is a alternative solution, however, before replacing the devices.xml, take backup of the existing devices.xml file in these folders.

Answer (score 4):

I removed the packages indicated in the api 22 in the sdk and the problem is not resolved.

I edited device.xml of
Applications / Android / android-sdk-macosx / system-images / android-22 / android-wear / x86
and of
Applications / Android / android-sdk-macosx / system-images / android-22 / android-wear / armeabi-v7a
I removed the lines containing "d:skin"

Finally restart eclipse and the problem was resolved!

Comment: It is `devices.xml`, not device.xml. In my case it was in `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\system-images\android-26\android-wear\x86\devices.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I removed these two

```
Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image
Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image
```

under **Android 9 (API 28)**

Comment: This did the trick for me without any side effects. In my case, Android 8.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS 10.10.2

1. Removed the lines, containing "d:skin" from `device.xml` from:

   - /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86
   - /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a
2. Restart the eclipse, the problem should be resolved.

Comment: There is a typo in this answer: It should read `devices.xml`, not device.xml. In my case it was in `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\system-images\android-26\android-wear\x86\devices.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of answer already given for this problem. Though this issue can happens for any API version, so just see the error line and find out android api version from path and platform name and go to the android sdk manager and delete related system image from sdk manager.

Comment: Also, once the `d:skin` lines are delete from `devices.xml`, a new problem pops up -- this time with 280dpi not being a facet-valid.

Answer (score 1):

execute with in under api level 19 right click on project go to preporty and then select android
[image: this pic look]

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't delete the system image (idk why), so I took the approach of deleting all occurrences of `g:skin` in any xml file since eclipse don't know what that is:

```sh
$ find . -type f -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i /d:skin/d
```

---

On windows you might want to run it within Cygwin or [cmder](http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the

- Android wear ARM EABI
- Android wear Intel x86

Than delete them and restart Eclipse IDE. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after removing the Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image and wear intel x86 Atom System image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it appears when I updated my sdk packages and added sdk 22 I removed all wear packages from sdk 22 as well as other sdks but problem wasn't resolved I **Updated all of my sdk packages** again from sdk manager then problem solved and error gone.

I think there's been few bugs with eclipse and android wear packages which are fixed in new updates available in sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have the latest Android SDK and just have to remove/delete the Android Wear system images and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Feel tired deleting the android-wear related packages each time upgrading the sdk?

Try to make some changes to `devices.xml` as following, you can edit the files by hand, or use some batching tools like **repl**.

**repl** is written by [me](https://github.com/lenik/uni/blob/master/text/repl/repl), add this line to sources.list and install:

```
echo 'http://deb.bodz.net/ unstable/' >>/etc/apt/sources.list
alias sagu='sudo apt-get update'
alias sagi='sudo apt-get install'
sagu
sagi repl
```

Then, remove those `<d:skin>` lines and replace `###dpi` to `hdpi` or whatever.

```
repl -r --filter=devices.xml --mode=regexp -- '<d:skin>.*</d:skin>' '' .
repl -r --filter=devices.xml -- '280dpi' 'hdpi' .
repl -r --filter=devices.xml -- '360dpi' 'xhdpi' .
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. To get rid of this issue, I followed the below steps and it worked for me.

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open file devices.xml(location of this will be shown in the error message) in a text editor.
3. Comment out all tags contains d:skin
4. Save files
5. Reopen Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Android Wear image, the same error is also displayed for Android TV as well, so if you do not have Android Wear image installed but have Android TV image installed, please uninstall that and then try.

Answer (score 0):

To remove error from eclipse for android there are few steps:-

[image]

1.open eclipse check all the error

2.In search tab open SDK manager

3.Remove all the value show as error in eclipse

4.After remove from sdk restart eclipse

Answer (score -1):

I solve this issue deleting the 10 packages
in my android sdk manage.

[image]