# Error in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Whenever i start eclipse i get this error :

> Error: Error parsing C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.

how to rectify it?

Comment: you should switch to Android Studio , if you are not sure yet then visit this link http://androidbinder.blogspot.in/2015/06/getting-started-with-android-studio-m.html

Comment: Check The below LLInk:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to remove package Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image available under Android 5.1.1 (API 22) to resolve this problem.

Reference - [Error Loading the sdk when eclipse is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started#30439524)

Answer (score 1):

[Error Loading the sdk when eclipse is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started)

theres an answer on their with screenshots you basically need to delete(uninstall) the package Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image available under Android 5.1.1 (API 22) if it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using Eclipse, and getting an error that looks like this:
[image]
Or this:
[image]
Solution= delete these items from your SDK Manager:
[image]

For some reason, this error only occurs with Eclipse. It doesn't happen with Android Studio.