# how to remove error cvc-complex-type.2.4.d:invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-sdk-tools

In my eclipse (juno) javaEE IDE I've finished the installation of the android plugin. Unfortunately the Android SDK is not loaded into the Eclipse IDE. It shows: "cvc-complex-type.2.4.d:invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin' No child element is expected at this point".
Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Better switch to Android Studio. Not yet convinced read this http://androidbinder.blogspot.in/2015/06/getting-started-with-android-studio-m.html

Answer (score 0):

Delete following Android Wear package(if you have installed) from SDK manager **(5.1 API 22)** & `restart` the eclipse

i) **Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image**

ii) **Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image**

For reference see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started#30439524).