# Eclipse (SDK Error)

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I'm having a problem with this error in my eclipse application. What's the reason behind this error? How can I correct it? I hope you can help me with this.

> [2015-08-19 22:05:28 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:
>
> Error: Error parsing C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.

Every time I opened it, that's the first message that will popped-up.

Comment: please check here...seems to be the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started/30440239#30440239

Comment: please upvote...if you have been helped