# Error when loading the SDK in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'd like to start by saying that I know the question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started/), as well as other places, but the solution does not work for me. This is my error message, as it is in most of the other posts:

```
Error: Error parsing
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-image\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

The suggested solution, which seems to work for everyone else, is to delete the two "wear" system image packages in both Android 22 and 23. I do not have those packages installed, but I'm still getting this message every time I try to load Eclipse. In fact, this started happening even before I installed any of the packages with the SDK manager.

It's also worth mentioning that I already tried re-installing the plugin for Eclipse. Did not work. Really not sure what the problem is. I don't even have the packages it's mentioning installed.

Comment: Don't use eclipse for android purpose. Standard IDE for android is `Android Studio` and you can download here  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I'm following my professor instructions. Also, I've tried Android Studio in the past. It was so slow I couldn't even work with it. It's probably my computer, but whatever the case, Android Studio isn't an option for me.