# Error message when starting up Eclipse Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time I start up Eclipse, it opens my project immediately. I get this error every time I start up. Then I click "OK", all the errors dissapear, and I'm able to start and run and do what I want with my application. I don't know if this is a big issue, if it's solvable, and what it actually means. Thought maybe you guys had some answers? This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove package **Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image** available under **Android 6.0 (API 23)** to resolve this problem.

Reference - [Error Loading the sdk when eclipse is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started#30439524)