# Android SDK Error when loading the SDK: invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin':No child element is expecting at this point

Tags: android, selenium, android-studio, sdk

This all the android version was installed in my SDK

[image]

[image]

I am using android sdk(eclipse) for appium automation testing, please help me How should I solve this problem?

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started might help you

Comment: I already remove the /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86
/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a both file in the android os file but i get the same issue, please review the image and help me once again

Answer (score 0):

Well the paths on the screenshots refer to `Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image` `API 25` and `API 26`,

[image]

[image]

so remove both these images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, since you are a newcomer to StackOverflow, consider upvoting/accepting as correct the answer that resolves your question