# How to fix this error which happens when eclipse program starts?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Recently, when I start eclipse program, always got below error. I did not see this issue before, seems the error started after I update the Android SDK. Could you please help?

[image]

I got some answers from here. They recommend me to uninstall some images from android sdk 5.1.1. I didn't install these images and even I cannot find them under 5.1.1 version as below.

[image]

Comment: Please read carefully questions and answer you can get the solutions from answers 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439524/error-loading-the-sdk-when-eclipse-is-started/30851089#30851089

Comment: @NileshPanchal Thanks. But it is not the same issue and I didn't install the wear image.

Answer (score 0):

[delete this guy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHD1U.png) 
the solution to above problem is to just delete(uninstall) the package Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image available under Android 5.1.1 (API 22) if it's installed. (No need to uninstall whole 5.1.1 package). May be there is some eclipse bug with this package.

Finally restart eclipse to see your changes.

If the problem still exists, try removing other Android Wear package also (i.e Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image)

Comment: I didn't install "package Android Wear ARM EABI v7a system image". I only installed Android 5.11 SDK Platform.

Comment: even though you dont install it, it is downloaded when you downloaded Android SDK. so try deleting(uninstalling) the package Android Wear ARM EABI v7a and Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, from the API, system image under Android 5.1.1 (API 22) resolves this problem. and then restart your IDE after deleting packages

Comment: thanks. I modified my question. Please check what is wrong with it.

Comment: did you check in all the android API's? i only see api 22

Comment: Yes. I checked all android API's